LinkedIn Api v2/me
Does this endpoint still exist? I want to get the users link to profile by getting their vanity name but with the new endpoint v2/userinfo but it doesn't return a vanity name field.
I tried all the old scopes and endpoints when using oauth but nothing works.

"I can't seem to be able to do that" - what does that mean?

What did you try? Did you get a response? If so, what was it?

The Oauth Screen doesn't even let me sign in, i just get this message Bummer, something went wrong.
In five seconds, you will be redirected to: localhost
